# Joomla search result urls are incorrect

Tags: joomla, joomla-sef-urls

I am using Joomla 2.5.4 and when I search using the Search component, the urls are not what they should be.

The expected url should look like this:

```
/desktop-projects/78-projects/76-project
/<MenuItem>/<Category>/<Article>
```

The actual search result urls look like this:

```
/component/content/article/78-projects/76-project
```

When it links to this /component/content/article/ style url, the page doesn't have the modules assigned to the menu item. Why doesn't it have the menu item in the url?

I have noticed that other modules/components link this way as well, is there something I'm missing ?

Comment: *cringes*....please update your Joomla version to 2.5.8 as this **might** fix your problem! In future always keep your Joomla version up to date as it fixes bugs and security threats. When there is an update, the quick icon is staring you right in the face, so you can't miss it and thus there should be no reason to be left behind.  If the update doesn't change this, then check for any parameters that migth affect the output of the search.

Comment: I updated it, still have the problem though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your search result is not showing on to the correct URL on your website.

In your search module, there is an option called "Set ItemID".
This allows you to select the menu item which the URL will use.

If you leave this blank, then your search component could use another menu item which is of type search.